# How to create database when hosting on Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask, heroku

I'm new to web dev and am trying to host my first site on Heroku.

I've finally gotten a live page, but when I try to use it, (based on the logs) it looks like my database hasn't been set up.

My `server.py` file has the following at the end:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        database.create_database(DATABASE)
        print("Database created")
    except database.DatabaseExistsError:
        print("Database already exists")

    app.run(debug=DEBUG)
```

And my Procfile is just `web: gunicorn server:app`.

However, I can't find the phrases "Database created" or "Database already exists" anywhere in the log.

My current understanding is that Heroku just runs `python server.py`, but if that were the case, it would set up the database. (And it hasn't, so I'm confused.)

So, I have two questions:

**1. Why isn't the database being created?**

**2. What can I do to get the database created?**

I thought I might try to add a setup step to the Procfile, but the format of the Procfile doesn't seem to have any option for that, so I'm not quite sure what to do.

Comment: Just saw [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) which says that sqlite is utterly awful for Heroku, but please humor me so I can learn more. Let's say that I'm okay with losing my database once every 24 hours - how would I get it set up?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can set up a database by running `python server.py` from the console in Heroku.

However, for some reason, this database seems to automatically be deleted / unusable. My guess is that this has something to do with [Heroku's warnings about using sqlite](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3).